# How to evaluate a non-ionized compound activity coefficient?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I know that the activity coefficient of compound such as $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is greater than unity averaging 1.13 for seawater ionic strengths, but how can we evaluate this value?

Answer (score 2):

Two separate conceptual problems here.

First, Debye-Hückel is a model for the approximation of electrolyte activities, but activities are conceptually distinct from concentrations for all other thermodynamic properties of a system, too, so activity coefficients can be derived from the apparent difference between any other thermodynamic property that relies on activities and its expected value due to concentration. For non-electrolytic solutions, activity coefficients are usually estimated from "contribution methods" - methods that apply contributions based on the empirical thermodynamic properties of large ranges of compounds, mathematically treated in a way that separate "contributions" can be statistically derived from the data, so that any new compound's activity coefficient can be estimated by the relevant contributions depending on its structure, environment, etc. These methods typically look at a wide variety of compounds and properties as a way to avoid singular effects and provide a good broad-range estimation of activities. You can read the Wikipedia articles on [MOSCED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSCED) and [UNIFAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIFAC) as a brief introduction to how these methods operate.

$\ce{NaHCO3}$, however, *is* ionised at seawater ionic strengths - it's a strong electrolyte that decomposes into $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{HCO3-}$, with separate activity coefficients. It is common, however, to provide activity coefficients of 1:1 salts as a *mean activity coefficient*, $\gamma_\pm$, which is the *geometric* average of the cationic and anionic activity coefficients:

$$ \gamma_\pm = \sqrt{\gamma_+\gamma_-}$$

or, for a general binary salt $\ce{A_xB_y}$,

$$ \gamma_\pm = \sqrt[x+y]{\gamma_{A}^{x} \gamma_{B}^{y}} $$

I suspect the reported activity coefficient for $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is therefore this mean coefficient:

$$ \gamma_\ce{NaHCO3} = \sqrt{\gamma_\ce{Na+} \gamma_\ce{HCO3-}} $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your good answer,
However, I'm asking about the activity of a non-ionized, I meant, like if we have a precipitant of  CaCO3 for instance, what's its activity?, please refer to: http://ocean.stanford.edu/courses/bomc/chem/lecture_02.pdf    (the table in Page 10)

Comment: Looking at your source, it's not clear to me what these values refer to or how they are derived. It seems that they are experimental values (given that they are presented in contrast, and approximated by, the Davies model discussed just above), but, to begin with, these activity coefficients aren't presented with correct dimensionality, and $\ce{Na}$-containing salts are strong electrolytes of which only a negligible amount will remain as bounded ionic pairs. I'm not sure where these values come from but since all ionic pairs have the same value makes me suspect they aren't actually (...)

Comment: (...) empirical but derived from electrostatic considerations (the only model the text seems to consider), which tend to assign identical values to compounds with the same charge, as explicitly discussed by the text with regards to Davies.

Comment: For instance, [Pitzer's 1980 paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/j100456a011), which seems to be an older source for a value that is oft-referenced in more recent studies, gives a value of around 0.6 for ionic strength ~0.7 and 25ºC, something that is in line with the free ion activity coefficients of $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{HCO3-}$ but quite different from the quoted value of 1.13. The experimental measurements Pitzer quotes are also in the 0.5-0.6 range although they do not measure exactly the same system.

Comment: Thank you, But I know that it's possible to find activity coefficient greater than 1, refer to the following question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8605/activity-coefficient-greater-than-1

Comment: It is definitely possible. So? What in what I have written implies it isn't possible?

Comment: I meant, that according to Debye-Hückle equation , it's not possible to find an average activity greater than 1, according to the equation you've previously mentioned, however, I need to find a simple equation to find out such like this activity coefficient.
I think Pitzer is a quite hard equation!

Comment: Debye-Hückel is valid only for very dilute solutions, with very low ionic strength (not to mention that for a neutral species Debye-Hückel predicts $\gamma = 1$). Activity coefficients larger than one typically appear only at high ionic strengths - characteristically quite larger than even seawater's. It is simply not possible to use a treatment of activity coefficients that is 1) simplistic, 2) accurate, and 3) applicable to concentrated electrolytic solutions. You can try [this](http://www.civil.northwestern.edu/EHE/COURSES/D68/Activities_EQ3.pdf) for a step-by-step discussion, though.

Comment: Thank you for the link you have shared, I'm already making a comparison between the activity coeficient equations (Helgeson, D&H, Ex.D&H, Davies, Güntelberg), and as you said, D&H has a limitation of 0.01 M ionic strength,
I understood, that you suspect the values of activity coef> 1, as they are the same, 1.13.... I would say that if we use i.e. Davies equation for monovalent ions, it will lead to a same value as well as bi or trivalent.
The values (1.13) in the reference I've shared, is it possible to be attained using a certain equation?
Thank you Very much for your answers!